# Deploy servlet on tomcat6 on ununtu lucid 10.04

Tags: tomcat, servlets, tomcat6

I am pretty new to tomcat6 application deployment. I am trying to deploy my helloworld severlet on tomcat6. But whenrver I use servlet url as http://192.168.2.10:8080/hello/HelloWorldExample2 , I am getting following error :

HTTP Status 404 - /hello/HelloWorldExample2

type Status report

message /hello/HelloWorldExample2

description The requested resource (/hello/HelloWorldExample2) is not available.

I have copied my servlet to /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps directory. Here are the contents of my webapp directory

ls -lR hello/*
hello/WEB-INF:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2010-11-23 17:07 classes
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  658 2010-11-23 17:41 web.xml

hello/WEB-INF/classes:
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1725 2010-11-23 17:07 HelloWorldExample2.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2532 2010-11-23 17:06 HelloWorldExample2.java

Here are the contents of my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">  
<display-name>HelloWorldExample2</display-name>  
<servlet>  
<servlet-name>HelloWorldExample2</servlet-name>  
<servlet-class></servlet-class>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>HelloWorldExample2</servlet-name>  
<url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

I am not sure why I am unable to load servlet. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web.xml is incorrect. It's missing the `<servlet-class>` which should be the the full name of the class including package. It seems to be `HelloWorldExample2` from your directory structure.

and you are using the `url-pattern` /hello which means you should try with the URL in the browser as:

http://192.168.2.10:8080/hello/hello

i.e. the format

```
http://<server:port>/<context-root>/<url-pattern>
```

Here the `<context-root>` is the name of your `webapp` `hello`

and the `<url-pattern>` is what you have specified in web.xml for that servlet.

If you want to access it as http://192.168.2.10:8080/hello/HelloWorldExample2 , then change the `<url-pattern>` for the `servlet-mapping` to /HelloWorldExample2

Also, the `display-name` in web.xml should match the webapp (hello) and not the servlet - but that wont cause the failure.